# Recursive callbacks: the first callback disables the following callbacks

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I'm triggering ray casting in my code:

```
m_rayCaster = new Qt3DRender::QRayCaster(m_rootEntity);
// Connect ray-caster signal to callback/slot
QObject::connect(m_rayCaster, &Qt3DRender::QRayCaster::hitsChanged, this, &MySceneClass::handleRayCasterHits);
// ...
// ...
m_rayCaster->trigger(origin, direction, length);
```

Ray caster results are handled by a callback/slot, which does the ray casting again recursively:

```
void MySceneClass::handleRayCasterHits(const Qt3DRender::QAbstractRayCaster::Hits hits)
{
    // ...
    // Handle ray caster hits
    // ...

    // Condition to stop ray casting
    m_counter++;
    if ( m_counter >= m_size )  {
        return;
    }


    // Recursive ray casting: trigger ray casting again:
    m_rayCaster->trigger(origin, direction, length);
}
```

---

The problem is when callback/slot `MySceneClass::handleRayCasterHits` returns, the ray-caster component will automatically disable itself, and no more ray casting tests can be performed. That's because the `RunMode` is set to `SingleShot`, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qt3drender-qabstractraycaster.html#runMode-prop).

One solution is to set the `RunMode` to `Continuous`, but it is not desirable, since it does the ray casting continuously and unnecessarily. By any chance, is there any other possible solution which I'm not aware of?

Comment: "One solution is to set the RunMode to Continuous, but it is not desirable, since it does the ray casting continuously and unnecessarily" the code as you've posted it would do this.  I assume there's actually a condition that means you don't always retrigger the ray cast?

Comment: @UKMonkey Right, actually there is a condition to stop ray casting ... which I added to my post

Comment: @UKMonkey I have also tried this: set run mode to `Continuous` when declaring the ray caster, and inside my (stop ray casting) condition, I set run mode to `SingleShot`. However, it didn't work ... I mean the ray casting is continuous regardless!

Comment: I'm trying to find the "trigger" function; but I'm not seeing it.  I once hit something similar to this in python; and the issue was that the emit (which is the macro mentioned in the qt docs) was processed immediately; rather than being added to the queue.  By just changing how the signal was emitted so that it wasn't actually recursive resolved the problem

Comment: @UKMonkey `trigger` is a Qt method of `Qt3DRender::QRayCaster` class. For some reason I cannot find its source code on Qt sources :(

Comment: Have a read of https://forum.qt.io/topic/67779/circular-signal-slot-connection-is-it-possible

Comment: @UKMonkey Your link helped me. Thanks =)

Comment: Glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@UKMonkey provided a [link](https://forum.qt.io/post/330895) on a comment which helped me solve the problem this way, I'm still not sure if this is the best way to solve it:

```
void MySceneClass::handleRayCasterHits(const Qt3DRender::QAbstractRayCaster::Hits hits)
{
    // ...
    // Handle ray caster hits
    // ...

    // // Wait 1 milli-second, then suggest doing next possible ray casting
    // // We wait for QRayCaster to be disabled, before doing the next ray casting
    QTimer::singleShot(1, this, &MySceneClass::handleRayCasterFinish);
}
```

This new slot actually triggers the next possible ray casting:

```
void MySceneClass::handleRayCasterFinish()
{

    while ( m_rayCaster->isEnabled() ) {
        qDebug() << __func__ << "Wait for ray caster to be disabled by the previous ray casting ... enabled: " << m_rayCaster->isEnabled();
        // Above debug message never gets logged, so I guess waiting for 1 milli-second is already enough
    }

    // Condition to stop ray casting
    m_counter++;
    if ( m_counter >= m_size ) return;

    // ...

    // Now we are sure that ray caster is disabled by previous ray casting test, therefore we can trigger the next ray casting test
    m_rayCaster->trigger(origin, direction, length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of a hackish workaround, but you could set up a **queue** of rays to be tested:

```
struct Ray {
    QVector3D origin;
    QVector3D direction;
    float length;
};

std::deque<Ray> m_raysEnqueued;
```

Then, you can initiate a ray trace by pushing a new ray onto the queue:

```
m_raysEnqueued.push_back({ origin, direction, length });
```

In your **frame callback**, you check the queue and process rays until it's empty:

```
while (!m_raysEnqueued.empty()) {
    Ray r = m_raysEnqueued.pop_front();
    m_rayCaster->trigger(r.origin, r.direction, r.length);
}
```

...and in the raycaster's callback, you simply enqueue more rays:

```
void MySceneClass::handleRayCasterHits(const Qt3DRender::QAbstractRayCaster::Hits hits)
{
    // ...
    // Handle ray caster hits
    // ...

    // Recursive ray casting: trigger ray casting again:
    m_raysEnqueued.push_back(Ray(origin, direction, length));
}
```